# Unable to use Postgis on Bluemix Compose for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, postgis

I have a Compose for Postgresql service on IBM Bluemix which isn't allowing me run PostGIS functions on my cloud foundry rails app.  I have run "CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS;" and I have also added the adapter to database.yml.  Compose for Postgresql says PostGIS comes installed by default

I am using Ruby on Rails with the rgeo gem and the error is

ERR NoMethodError: undefined method `st_point' for #

Can you please let me know if there is anything I need to do to get PostGIS working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.  The problem was with the rgeo gem and the adapter.  I needed the postgis:// adapter for working with the gem.

Bluemix does not allow you to change the adapter in their connections.  It will always be postgresql.  To get around this I set a CUSTOM_DATABASE_URL environment variable with the connection string `postgis://<username>:<password>@host:port/<db_name>`.  Using the cf client this would look like

`cf set-env <app-name> CUSTOM_DATABASE_URL postgis://<username>:<password>@host:port/<db_name>`

Then in the command for my container in the manifest.yml, I prepended setting DATABASE_URL = CUSTOM_DATABASE_URL, specifically

`DATABASE_URL=$CUSTOM_DATABASE_URL &&.....`

Its a workaround for now until Bluemix allows us to change the adapter in the connections.

Answer (score 0):

Please raise a support request asking for the postgis plugin to be enabled on your compose instance.